# How can I get selectize to insert the text of the option, not just the value?

Tags: jquery, select, selectize.js

I am trying to use Selectize.js to handle a multi-select field in my form. When you select an option from the dropdown, it adds a selection to the select field , but only adds the data value. Does anyone know if there is an easy way to get Selectize to add the text from the option as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .getItem(value) method.

https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_options

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/pzekurvp/5/

```
var selectizedElement, $selectizedElement;

$selectizedElement = $('#select-state').selectize({
    onItemAdd: function (value, $item) {
        alert(this.getItem(value)[0].innerHTML);
    }
});

selectizedElement = $selectizedElement[0].selectize;
```