# how to get text from <option> in <select> with display none set by selectize

Tags: jquery, html, css, selectize.js

I am using seletize 0.11.0 for bootstrap2. I want get the text from `<option>` with specific value.

I tried:

```
$("#id_sel option[value='1']").text();
```

I got nothing.

The html element `<select>` has attribute display as none.

Well, how to do that? Thanks for your consideration.

**EDIT**

Samples

```
<body>
    <select id="id_sel" multiple='multiple'>
        <option selected='selected' value='1'>first</option>
        <option value='2'>second</option>
        <option selected='selected' value='3'>third</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

js

```
$("#id_sel").selectize();
alert($("#id_sel option[value='1']").text());
```

**NOW I KNOW**

selectize [remove text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481041/how-can-i-get-selectize-to-insert-the-text-of-the-option-not-just-the-value) between option tags and make the display of select as none. It is wired.

so select at runtime would looks like:

```
<select id="id_sel" multiple="multiple" class="selectized" style="display: none;">
    <option selected='selected' value='1'></option>
    <option value='2'></option>
    <option selected='selected' value='3'></option>
</select>
```

Well I still dont know how to get text.

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: which html element has attribute display none (select or option)

Comment: I put it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdouble/crnhdvjd/2/)

Comment: `<select>` has attribute display none. @AnkitAgrawal

Comment: Have you tried with `selectize.getValue();` ?

Comment: Not works when using getValue(). I am not quite sure about how to use it. Can you try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdouble/crnhdvjd/2/). Thank you. @urbz

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#id_sel option").each(function()
{
    // here you can use $(this).text()
});
```

Comment: I'd like to get the text of option not the value.

Comment: then you can use $(this).text()

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#id_sel option").each(function()
        {
            if(!$(this).is(':visible'))
            {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });                        
    });

</script>



<select id="id_sel">
    <option>select</option>
    <option style="display: none;">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

by this code you can get value of hide option field

Comment: It seems not work for `text()`. I need get text between <option> and </option>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there should be some api to get that. If not, it is weired. I have tried [getOption() and getItem()](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md). It is not work. Selectize do not add text to option tags for the edition which I used. It make `<select>` as none, and create a group of divs to cover the position of `<select>`. In my edition, it looks like:

```
<div class="selectize-control multi">
    <div class="selectize-input items full has-options has-items">
        <div data-value="1" class="item">first</div>
        <div data-value="2" class="item">second</div>
        <input ....
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

For now, I use jquery multiple selector to get text.

```
$(".selectize-control .selectize-input div").each(function() {
    if (1 == $(this).data("value")) {
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Or identified by id

```
$("#id_sel").siblings(".selectize-control").find(".selectize-input div").each(function() {
    if (1 == $(this).data("value")) {
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Hope this helpful for other people. The best answer should be use api to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works as you mentioned:

```
$("#id_sel option").val("1").text();
```